# Lineage or Chart of Srimad Bhagavatam

Tags: bhagavata-purana

on reading Srimad Bhagavatam it gets quite confusing on where did it all start and who recited initially and was passed on to whom. Can anyone share a chart showing how Bhagavatam was passed on?

Comment: Do you mean the conversation between Sukadeva Muni and Maharaja Praikshita or how the Bhagavata was revealed to Praikshita?